# How do I get the data in a file using "CSV, Reader"?

Tags: python

**I am trying to use this code:**

```
from csv import reader
c = open('marvel.csv')
v = reader(c)
print(v)
```

However, I only get this

```
<_csv.reader object at 0x103d92c90>
```

**When I am supposed to get all Marvel Superheros names, age, gender, etc...**

Comment: There are a number of examples in the [documentation of the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open(input_file_path, 'rU') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in rows:
        print row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the rows with:

```
r = reader(c)

for v in r:
    print(v)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie so I don't understand, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Without seeing your CSV file, I can only guess at what the problem might be.  I solved your specific problem, but you have more problems that aren't obvious from what you posted.  You should look at the documentation for the `csv` module.  You can pass several keyword args to `reader`, such as `delimeter`, `quotechar`, and `lineterminator`.  For instance, `","`, `"\n"`, and `"\n"` might work, but it depends on your format.  It's also possible that you may need to open the file with `"rb"`.

Comment: So should I send you the file

Comment: Okay so yes it is a problem with the file cause I just made a new file and tried it with that file and it was totally working.

Comment: The thing is there isn't just one CSV format.  The standard field separator is comma, line terminator is newline, and quote character is double-quote.  But some CSV files use different conventions.

Comment: So you need to look at the file, then (1) figure out the field delimeter, (2) figure out the quote character, and (3) figure out the line terminator character.  Then provide them as arguments to `reader` as I explained.

Comment: In fact, are you *certain* it's even a CSV file?

Comment: That link points to a web page.  It's not clear what file you have in mind.

Comment: @Eletrix please try the solution i have provided. It seems to work for the file you have linked. It will open the file in universal-newline-mode